# Sent data using Jquery Ajax to another page not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I sent some data using ajax from test.php to another page order.php, but when i navigate to order.php and try to echo the data, I get the " Undefined index..." error message.

I have done console.log in the text.php file and confirmed that the data values were successfully set. But it doesn't reflect on the order.php file. I also started session in both files.

NOTE: Before i can send ajax data to DB, I will need to get the data via $_POST['data'] in order.php and save in a variable so that i can proceed to insert the values in the DB. In this case, I CAN'T even get the data. For some reason, the data posted to order.php did not get to the file. That's the issue I want to resolve. How can I get my ajax post data to order.php so that i can use it for something else?

Please what could be wrong with my code? See Code Below:

**test.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".addItemBtn").click(function(event){
                    var $form = $(this).closest(".formclass");
                    var qty = $form.find(".naira-input").val(); //form input`
                    var total = $('.amount').html(); //from javascript innerhtml

                    
                $.ajax({
                     url:'order.php',
                     method:'post',
                     data:{grandTotal:total, nairaRate:qty}, // dont worry about this. The values are succesfully set in console.log
                     success:function(response)
                     {
                          console.log(response+' values were sent successfully');// I tested and confirmed that data was sent successfully
                    }
                     
                });
            });
        });


        </script>
```

**order.php**

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    
 $_SESSION['grandTotal']= $_POST['grandTotal'];
      $_SESSION['nairaRate']=$_POST['nairaRate'];

    echo $_SESSION['grandTotal']; // I get Undefined index error here
    echo  $_SESSION['nairaRate']; // I get Undefined index error here
    
    ?>
```

Comment: When you use AJAX, the idea is to NOT have to navigate elsewhere. Save your data to the DB in order.php and `echo {"succes":"Your order was received and has order number #".$orderNumber."}";` for example. Then you can do show response.success to the user

Comment: Use pure Javascript (fetch or XMLHttpRequest) to post data to order.php without page refreshing. You don't need JQuery.

Comment: @mplungjan : Are you saying i cannot use data posted with Ajax in another page unless i save it in a DB first and access it manually in next page?

Comment: Yes unless you save it in local/sessionStorage too, but why not get the data from the dB so ppl can link to the other page too

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner : The idea is that i need to navigate to order.php onclick event and use the Ajax data posted in order.php

Comment: @mplungjan : Please clarify. A sample code from you will help a lot sir.

Comment: @mplungjan : Remember; before i can send ajax data to DB, I will need to get the data via $_POST['data'] in php and save in a variable so that i can proceed to insert the values in the DB. In this case, I can't even get the data. For some reason, the data posted to order.php did not get to the file. That's the issue I want to resolve. How can I get my ajax post data to order.php so that i can use it for something else?

Comment: In order save it in the dB instead or as well as in the session

Comment: In order to save it in dB. That is what I meant. If i had gone ahead to send data to DB in order.php file, nothing will be sent because $_POST['data'] is empty. Or do you think otherwise? Please help with some code. That will really really help

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate to order.php the code which **assigns** values to the session runs **again**, only thing time you haven’t made a post request so the values aren’t set.

Don’t use the same endpoint for displaying the data as you do for setting it.